# How to run multiple terminal consoles at the same time?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

I have connected to three raspberry pis using ubuntu.I run a shell file in all three consoles using "enter". Because of this it take few seconds delay to run each file. I want to know how to run the shell file in all three consoles at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tmux` which a "terminal multiplexer" that you can install on your client, e.g. on ubuntu it's `apt-get install tmux`

It has a feature called "synchronized panes",
for you each pane would be a shell opened to one of your raspberry pi devices

When you activate the synchronized panes, the same key inputs will go to all of the panes, the command is `:setw synchronize-panes`

http://tmux.github.io/

Comment: this is okay but in my case im connected to 3 different rpis. Using panes i cant connect to three different but only one. can windows be synchronized ?

Comment: Open 3 panes, then connect to the devices from each pane, then you can run and view results from commands simultaneously on all devices

Comment: i tried to connect as you say from panes but it does not allow me to connect. why is that ?

Comment: Not sure, but I would imagine you can e.g. ssh into each device individually in each pane as a starter, personally I use `tmuxinator` to pre-load all my windows and panes for a project. If you can ssh from a window you should be able to ssh from a pane too, as long as you aren't accidentally trying to ssh from a wrong place, make sure you initiate the ssh login from the correct client e.g.

Comment: what i did was open a terminal and use tmux and create two more panes. i connected with one of my Rasp pis and tried to connect to another but i couldnt. but i can connect to the same one

Comment: Maybe you're connecting from a device 1 device 2 when you should have connected from your PC to device 1, and again PC to device 2 etc